# Getting content URI for a file in asset folder

Tags: java, android

I have a zip file in my asset folder for which I want a content uri.

I am able to get a file uri using this:

```
final Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("file:///android_asset/xyz.zip"));
```

For content uri I tried using:

```
final Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.example.myproject/xyz.zip");
```

But it is not working?

Comment: What exactly do you need the `Uri` for? Are you trying to share that zip with another app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
InputStream inputStream = am.open("myfoldername/myfilename");
File file = createFileFromInputStream(inputStream);
final Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

private File createFileFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
try{
  File f = new File(my_file_name);
  OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
  byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
  int length = 0;

  while((length=inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
  }

  outputStream.close();
  inputStream.close();

  return f;
 }catch (IOException e) {
     //Logging exception
 }

return null;
}
```